# How do I fix my fridge that is not refrigerating?

Tags: refrigerator, cooling, ice, freezer

My refrigerator (*Frigidaire model #frt18b4aw8*) is not refrigerating the refrigeration compartment, however the freezer compartment is freezing properly.

I opened the back panel in the freezer and saw that it, and the channel to the fridge, are clear from ice.

How do I fix my fridge that is not refrigerating?

Comment: Got a question? You haven't actually asked one. If I infer that the freezer is cold (you didn't say) then I'd guess that there's a fan not working to move air between the refrigerator and the coils in the freezer area.

Comment: @Ecnerwal thank you, I edited as per your suggestions. Please post a answer explaining how to replace/fix the fan.

Comment: I don't know anything about your particular fridge. I know how the vast majority of modern fridges work, which implies a fan problem (if the freezer is cold, which you have still not clarified) though there could also be a different problem, such as a thermostat or control board failing to call for the fan to run, or a broken wire / loose connector causing the fan not to get power.

Comment: @Ecnerwal "the freezer compartment is freezing cold"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does it make sense for a freezer to work , but the refrigerator to not work?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3113/does-it-make-sense-for-a-freezer-to-work-but-the-refrigerator-to-not-work)

Comment: Depending on the fridge, you may have a failed compressor (if the fridge has two...more expensive ones do), or there may be some reason other than blocked vents preventing the air from getting to the fridge section from the evaporator in the freezer section (such as a failed fan). Other possibilities involve the electronics that control said components. See proposed duplicate.

Comment: Another possibility: The fridge has leaked some refrigerant. Some fridges expand it first in the freezer compartment and then in the fridge compartment, so if there is not enough, only the freezer is cooled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming someone didn't screw around with the refrigerator's thermostat or temperature setting...

Typically, that problem is due to failure of the circulating fan housed in the freezer...thermostats almost never fail. Hopefully, you notice there is no or very little noise being made by the refrigerator when you open the freezer.

It doesn't matter how cold the freezer is if the refrigerator isn't cold. There shouldn't be silence unless and until the refrigerator's desired temperature is reached.